# How to avoid age ranges overlapping C#

Tags: c#, list, range, overlap

Can you help me to get a better way to verify or avoid that a new age range overlaps with an existing ones??

I have a list of "age ranges" entity which have the minAge, maxAge properties and I want to add a new object of type age range to my List but it must not overlap the existing age ranges.

```
List[0] (MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 2)
List[1] (MinAge = 3, MaxAge = 18)
List[2] (MinAge = 19, MaxAge = 54)
```

If I want to add Min = 10 and Max = 16 ... It must be avoided. I need to add just the values that continue with the series.

I was trying to validate each by each index from the list min and max between the ranges but I want to know if there is another way to do this with linq or something similar

Example:

```
foreach(Age age in list)
{
     if(age.min >= min && max <= age.max)
     {
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return !list.Any(x => x.min <= min && x.max >= min || x.min <= max && x.max >= max);
```

Comment: A list: `(1 3)(4 5)`, an input: `(-100 0)`. `3 >= -100` so `Any()` would return `True`. Is it intended? Then we change an input to `(-100 2)` so it was an overlap and see exactly the same result: `True`.

Comment: yep, it will work now, +1. And just a side note: there is a "standard" simplification for such a long check as I put in my answer. It's widely used to check if one interval overlaps another :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
.Any(i => i.max >= min && i.min <= max);
```

this would return `True` if there is an overlap

Comment: +1 for simpler and better expression, at least this is not easy to spring up right in my mind :)

Comment: @King King: actually I memorized it as the max of one interval should be `>` than min of another, and min < max